# after issuing `blogdown::serve_site()` the R Studio console hangs

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

`R 3.5.1`. `blogdown 0.9`. On Windows R Studio preview `v 1.2.1237` I issue the command `blogdown::serve_site()` and I get the following console output:

```
Serving the directory C:\Users\jhunter\wd\blog at http://127.0.0.1:4321
```

The issue is I'm not dropped to a command prompt after issuing the command. The R Studio console just hangs at this point until I hit the red-stop-sign or quit out of R. I still can edit my `.md` and `.toml` files in the pane and `Ctrl-S` to make them render. I just can't do anything in the console.

If I recall my Linux box does not exhibit this behavior. After I issue the `blogdown::serve_site()` command I get the same `serving the directory` message above, but I also get something along the lines of `to stop server use servr::daemon_stop()` **AND** most importantly I'm dropped back to the console with a blinking cursor.

Why is my Windows R Studio console hanging after issuing this `blogdown::serve_site()` command? Is this a bug or am I potentially doing something wrong?

Comment: [When in doubt, try upgrade.](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/)

Answer (score 0):

Running `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` and also `tinytex::tlmgr_update()` fixed the issue. Thanks Yihui.